# Angular 5 Download file from dropbox and Upload it to AWS s3

Tags: node.js, angular, dropbox, angular5, dropbox-sdk-js

I am currently using dropbox file picker to download the file. I got the download link after selection of file using dropbox picker.

Is there any possibility that we can save it inside bytestream in browser and upload it to server(Node.JS) using http post call ?

Or Is there any alternative to this scenario ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of downloading and reuploading the file on the browser, I would have this step to be processed on the server side.

You can use [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/developers) and [S3](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js) sdk's and follow the steps below:

1. Make a call to the server that will send IDs of the list of files available in  Dropbox.
2. Let the user select a file in the angular app and send the selected file's resource identifier back to the server.
3. Download the file and then re-upload it to the S3 on the server side.
4. Display the result/status back to the user.

Is there any reason you want this to be done in the frontend?